# How to retrieve full file path from DIR pointer?

Tags: c++, dirent.h

From a `DIR*` variable from `<dirent.h>`, how do I get the full file path (e.g. "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/planning")?

**Note**: This needs to work on Linux.

Comment: Which operating systems does this need to work on? Is a solution that just works on Linux acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the `DIR` object that gives you the name of the directory that the `DIR` object is reading. There is no function in the C library that does this.

You will need to implement this logic yourself. Wherever you open a `DIR`: save the name of the directory you opened, and consult it as needed.

Or, in modern C++, you can also use [the filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), instead of this C API.